# excel 2007 first and last occurrence stock data

Tags: excel

I have a table like this:

```
BANKNIFTY
BANKNIFTY
BANKNIFTY
BANKNIFTY
BANKNIFTY
NIFTY
NIFTY
NIFTY
```

I want to find address of the cell on which a text occurs first time and 
last time in a column (e.g in above address of first row and sixth row in case of banknifty, and 7th row and 9th row in case of Nifty).

I tried using match function, but it always gives last row number irrespective 
of my search. Please note that data is very big, above is just a part of that.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Occurrence  `=MATCH("banknifty",B:B,0)` 
Last Occurrence `=MATCH(2,INDEX(1/(B1:B1001="banknifty"),,))`

Comment: Sir,i used =MATCH(2,INDEX(1/(B:B="banknifty"),,)) and giving last adress.This was done as i dont know how many rows a particular symbol takes.However it is taking lot of computer resources.Is there any way such that in place of B:B we give B:last row data so that computation is avoided.Thanks

Comment: what do you hope to achieve? can you give further idea of your problem